# Grape entities and Single table inheritance

Tags: inheritance, ruby-grape, grape-entity

Let's say i have Base class "Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base" and 2 child classes "Attachment::Video < Attachment" , "Attachment::Image < Attachment".

```
present Attachment.all, with: API::Entities::AttachmentEntity
```

But i want to use different entities for different subclasses. 
Attachment::Video should be present with API::Entities::AttachmentEntity::Video and so on

Is it possible in grape ?

Comment: you have to loop and build the json manually.

Comment: if you are gonna represent different json structures, you batter expose those in different names. so that would make clients work easy